# jax-rs jersey server for android 5?

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

we are in the process of porting the server part of a webservice written in jersey 2 to android.

We tried deploying it in an embded jetty. Unfortunatly, we had missing java core dependencies

- sun.misc.Unsafe
- java.awt.image
- javax.imageio
- java.lang.management
- javax.naming

Does this mean we won't be able to use it on android? there's a [post explaining how the client part could work](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on1) configuring the framework through HK2 public API. But I don't think this could be applied for what we want.

What are the other options if we want to build the server part of a rest api on android? We already considered nanohttp, but this seams too low level, we'd like to keep on using jax-rs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Embedded jetty is fine enough to handle jerser service. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: we're missing the dependencies mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jersey there is a check if unsafe methods are supported or not on the given platform. So the components using sun.misc.Unsafe can be removed, with a small modification in the code to use the fallback solution.

java.lang.management and javax.management are used for monitoring and diagnostics. It is in beta stage and it is disabled by default. So the problematic "JMX MBeans with statistics" component can be simply removed.

java.awt.image and javax.imageio are used in RenderedImageProvider.java
I don't know exactly what it does, but on Jersey 1.x it is present but not used. So probably it also can be removed. If it is needed it has to be reimplemented using native Android components.

There is an another problem with some external libraries required by Jersey: they are from the standard java.* or javax.* namespace and Android thinks that they depend on other "core" libraries, which is not available on Android as Android doesn't support the full JDK. They has to be repackaged (using Jarjar) or the "--core-library" option has to be specified during compilation to eliminate core library check.

I don't know about Grizzly, but Jetty works fine on Android.

Best regards,
kukukk